# Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 crashed my laptop

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, crash

I had been having many problems recently and tried to upgrade to 20.04, it took a long time to figure out how to clear some obstacles to even starting that process, but after I removed skype it seemed like it finally was happening, then somehow everything crashed. The answers I've seen all say things like do ctrl + F1 and then suggests commands but I can't even get to anything where I could enter any commands or anything. The options I get are: ubuntu; advanced options for ubuntu; uefi firmware settings. I've tried all the recovery mode settings under advanced options and nothing works, I get the Dell logo on black screen or endlessly flashing cursor. Somehow trying to upgrade seems to have destroyed my system. How can I fix this?

Comment: Release upgrades should not be expected to solve preexisting problems. It can actually complicate things and it will bury potentially helpful logs. I suggest that you reinstall either 20.04 or 22.04.  That is the most prudent path forward. You can use a live session from installation media to retrieve any files in case your backups were insufficient.

Comment: You haven't said if you're talking about a desktop or server install; you can re-install a Ubuntu Desktop system without losing any data, and having your *manually installed* packages auto-reinstalled (where they're available in Ubuntu repositories) which is an easy option if you're using a desktop system...  Backup first as mistakes are easy to make... (FYI: *I use this method 40+ times per year as a method of QA-testing & upgrading some system kept for support purposes; which include release changes too; this assumes a desktop system though*)

Comment: I should add that I'm getting this at the bottom of a long string: 
end Kernel panic -  not syncing: UPS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0.0)

Comment: @Nmath if by "use a live session from installation media" you mean a CD, that is not applicable, I'm on a dell laptop, no cd drive. If you mean bootable usb, could I make one on an ancient Mac?

Comment: **Any** Ubuntu installation media, which is typically USB these days. That would be quite outdated and useless for many people if you had to install Ubuntu from a CD drive... Creating installation media is the first step towards [installing Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: @guiverc yes, desktop. I had started the process in terminal. But I don't understand how I could possibly re-install? Some answers I saw for this "end kernel" message suggest doing something in "grub menu". I did get to something that says grub, I think I got there by entering "e" or "c" when those options were given at tthe bottom (for edit before booting, or for control, respectively) but nothing I type in that grub thing is recognized, it even says it doesn't recognize any such command as "sudo"! So, how can I do anything?

Comment: Your system could be entirely destroyed and as long as the hardware is fine you can reinstall the operating system. It doesn't matter how messed up things are, reinstalling the OS wipes the slate clean. Just follow the tutorial I linked which walks you through the entire process from start to finish. In your case, you'll want to "Erase disk and install" when it asks you where you want to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I recall trying to make such a USB a couple years ago on the old Mac using Etcher, and the OS of the Mac was already too ancient. I may have to buy a new Windows laptop just to do this, but I guess its the only way. If I select "erase disk and install" will I lose all data that is on there? (I did back up everything except for one document I'd been working on for a few hours)

Comment: Yes, erasing the disk is exactly what it sounds like.  Instead of buying a new device just to create an Ubuntu USB, consider borrowing a computer or using a public library.

Comment: Please note DISK refers to the whole disk drive (*physical disk*), including all partitions on it.  If you physical disk is partitioned into two *logical* drives, say C: and D: - an *erase disk* will destroy both *logical* partitions and create a new partition using the space for both.  If however C: and D: where on two physical disk drives; it'll only erase one. Most machines have a single disk in them, which can be partitioned into multiple *logical* smaller partitions (commonly called *drives* & sometimes wrongly called '*disks*' by users)

Comment: Is there some way I can do it without erasing the disk drive, then, and then erase it after retrieving the aforementioned document?

Comment: To get your document; I'd just boot a *live* system (eg. Ubuntu Desktop installation media & select "Try Ubuntu), copy & save your document to somewhere safe then consider re-install as I suggested, or follow other suggestions.  The re-install is just "*Something else*", select your existing partitions & ensure you don't format.. the no-format of "/" causes a "*upgrade via re-install*" type of install..  If you have partition encryption (install from 17.10 or earlier) you may need additional packages before you start install..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I was finally able to make a bootable USB and complete the upgrade (there are no public libraries here in the Third World country I live in, but I was able to borrow another laptop). Now I find that one of the problems that prompted me to upgrade apparently still persists however - sometimes when I turn it on it doesn't detect wifi networks, and when I check in settings "no wifi adapter found"